# DB Connect constants throwing errors on ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm making a test prep app. I store questions and answers in a DB, and when the user is taking the quiz, I instantiate the Question class defined in `content.php` and call its getQuestions function to loop through and return data for the current question ID.

```
    $question = new Question($questionID); 
    echo $question->getQuestions();
```

Which connects to the DB, runs the query for that question ID, and echos out a number of options as radio buttons:

```
while ($row = $imgpath->fetch_assoc()) {
            $this->id = $row['question_id'];
            echo '
                    <p>' . $row['question']. '</p><br/>
                    <br/><input type="radio" name="choice1" id="c1"> ' . $row['choice_1'] . ' , etc
```

The issue I'm having is, when the user selects a choice, and clicks the **check Answer** button, I'm getting breaking DB connection constants...

```
Use of undefined constant DB_HOST - assumed 'DB_HOST' in C:\wamp\www\...\php\dbconnect.php on line 2
```

The check answer button:

```
echo '<br/><br/><button id="checkAnswer" onclick="checkVal()">Check Answer</button>';
```

Which calls:

```
                function checkVal() {
                    var chx = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
                    var userAnswer = null;
                    for (var i = 0; i < chx.length; i++) {
                        if (chx[i].type === 'radio' && chx[i].checked) {
                            userAnswer = chx[i].id;
                        }
                    }

                    $.get("./php/content.php", {_input : userAnswer, "_functionToRun" : "getAnswer"},
                        function(returned_data) {
                            $("#output").html(returned_data);
                        }
                    );
                }
```

Which returns:

```
$functionToRun = (isset($_GET['_functionToRun']) ? ($_GET['_functionToRun']) : 0); 
if (isset($_GET['_functionToRun']) && !empty($_GET['_functionToRun'])) {
    include 'dbconnect.php';
    if ($functionToRun == "getAnswer") {
        $qry = 
            "SELECT q.*
            FROM questions q
            WHERE question_id = $questionID";

        $result = $mysqli->query($qry); 
        mysqli_close($mysqli);

        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo $row['answer'];    
    }
}
```

**Question is:** Why only on the ajax call are the dbconnection constants coming back undefined? Yet when I first load the page, the constants throw no errors?

---

dbconnect file: in `root/php folder`, in same folder as content.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_UN, DB_PW, DB_NAME);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (Error code: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . ")... " . $mysqli->connect_error;

}
```

config.php: file in the root of website

```
if(!defined("DB_HOST")) define("DB_HOST", "stuff");
if(!defined("DB_UN")) define("DB_UN", "stuff");
if(!defined("DB_PW")) define("DB_PW", "stuff");
if(!defined("DB_NAME")) define("DB_NAME", "stuff");
```

`config.php` is loaded from my `index.php` file which determines which HTML to load:

```
include './config.php';
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";
switch($action) {   
    case 'practice':
        require(TEMPLATE_PATH . "/practice.php");
        break;
    case 'about':
        require(TEMPLATE_PATH . "/about.php");
        break, etc...
```

Comment: `Use of undefined constant DB_HOST - assumed 'DB_HOST'` is a NOTICE, not a fatal error. It might very well be happening on first page load and not showing depending on your error reporting level. Where is DB_HOST defined and what does your dbconnect.php file look like? (Minus any sensitive db credentials)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `DB_HOST` is defined in `config.php`, it seems that you do include `config.php` in the initial page load, but not when you call `content.php` from AJAX.

Now, the part that includes `config.php` is missing from your question, so I can't see exactly what is going on, but likely:

- config.php is included in an if of which the condition is not met.
- content.php is in a subfolder or for another reason the path to config.php is invalid.

To solve this, I would take a couple of steps: Firstly, use `require_once` instead of `include` for the config file. This would cause the script to fail with a clear message when the file cannot be found. Also, you can call it multiple times without problems, so every file that needs the config can safely include it with `require_once`.

Secondly, consider including the config file in dbconnect.php. After all, that file uses the constants, so it makes sense that it includes the config file they are in.

Comment: The config file is included in my `index.php` file, see above

Comment: Also, yes, `content.php` is in a subfolder `php/`. In `content.php` file I do `require_once './config.php';` at the top of the file

Comment: I agree with GolezTrol. Your ajax call is requesting `"./php/content.php"` and bypassing your index.php file. This is ok, but then you should use `require_once('/path/to/config.php')` in content.php or dbconnect.php.

Comment: @JohnMcMahon Okay, in my `dbconnect.php`, located in `root/php/`, I include `config.php` located in root using `require_once('./config.php');`. I know to access file in parent folder, you need to do two dots, as such `require_once('../config.php');` but both return " No such file or directory" error... with `..`, it returns error right away, with `.`, it returns error when I run ajax

Comment: I've ran into include path errors before when including a file that in turn includes other files. One way to fix this is to use absolute instead of relative paths. (Absolute path from the "/" root directory of the server file system, not your web root.)